# How to change the value of a variable on the click of a button

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout

```
enterbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        int get_form_edittext=Integer.parseInt(edtx.getText().toString());
        if(get_form_edittext==111){
        flag=1;}
        else{
            flag=0;

        }
```

First I have initialized the flag variable with 0. I want that if the user enters "o" on the edit text and then presses the enter button the value of the flag variable should be change with 1, else the value should stay 0. I have implemented the above logic but on the click of enter the app has crash.

Logcat

```
Process: com.sumita.tic_tac_toe, PID: 30411
   java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "o"
           at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:608)
              at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:643)
              at com.sumita.tic_tac_toe.MainActivity$2.onClick(MainActivity.java:36)
              at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6412)
              at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25341)
              at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6977)
              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
              at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:528)
              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:910)
```

Comment: can you provide more logs??

Comment: logcat error text

Answer (score 0):

You must be declare `inputType="number"` in your `EditText`.

- Your `activity_main.xml`

```xml
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="number" />
```

- Your `MainActivity.java`

```java
button.setOnClickListener(v -> {
    String editTextString = editText.getText().toString().trim();
    if (editTextString != null && !editTextString.isEmpty()) {
        int value = Integer.parseInt(editTextString);
        flag = value == 111 ? 1 : 0;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

bro that's because 'o' is not an Integer. the logcat error says it has failed on converting "o" to Integer.
do it like this
**SOLUTION 1:**

```
  String text = editText.getText().toString();
    if (text != null && !text.isEmpty()) {
       if(string.matches("\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?")){
         // here the string is a number
         // you can now check for 111 here
       }else{
         // and here the string is not a number 
       }
    }
```

**SOLUTION 2:**

use a try-catch:

```
   try{
    int get_form_edittext=Integer.parseInt(edtx.getText().toString());
     if(get_form_edittext==111){
       flag=1;
     }else{
       flag=0;
     }
    }catch(Exception e){
       flag=0;
    }
```

**SOLUTION 3:**
make your editText numerical:
add this to your edit text in your XML

```
android:inputType="number"
```